# How to fetch a .py file from web host

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a py file that contains lots of useful functions that are annoying to type out manually, and I use it across different projects and update it constantly. I know this solution isn't perfect, so if you have any ideas on how else I could do this, that would be helpful. For the web host, I want to get the file, then run it in a python (3) shell using `import`.
I am a bit new to stackoverflow, so please help me improve in the comments or ask for more info!

Comment: Do you regularly change computer or not have persistent storage?

Comment: I change the host to update it for more functions and what not, but I would like to have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

This is the file I want to execute from anywhere:

```
# Fibonacci.py
n = int(input("Nth Fibo?"))
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
for i in range(0,n):
        nf = n1 + n2
        n1 = n2
        n2 = nf
        print(i,nf)
```

This file is in `/Documents/Fibonacci.py`, therefore, I can serve it with:

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0 8888 --directory Documents/
```

This server can be on the cloud or LAN.

Now you can get the file, save it and import it.

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:8888/Documents'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('myfile.py','wb').write(r.content)

import myfile.py
```

Comment: Yeah, I already use this code to fetch from my web host, and I've just figured how to delete the file and re-fetch it.